# How to show a dir name of last commits?

Tags: git, terminal, git-log

I have such script

```
git log -n 3 --pretty=format:"%h  %s "
```

that shows me abbreviated commit hash and subject of three last commits like:

```
hash1 "subject1"
hash2 "subject2"
hash3 "subject3"
```

But I want to see

```
hash "name of commit folder" "subject"
```

without full path to the folder and contents of this dir. Just name.
How can I do that?
Thank in advance!

Comment: What do you mean with `commit folder`?

Comment: folder that was commited by 
`git add "name of folder"`
`git commit -m "subject"`

Comment: And what do you expect if multiple directories are changed in a single commit?

Comment: Note that Git never stores *folders* at all: it just stores files whose names contain forward slashes. It's your OS, not Git, that insists on treating `foo/bar` as a file named `foo` in a folder named `bar`: Git thinks of this as a file named `foo/bar`. (This is due to the fact that Git makes commits from Git's *index*, not from your working tree; files in Git's index are stored with path-names with forward slashes in them. This is true even on Windows, where the OS uses `foo\bar` internally.)

Comment: When you run `git add foo`, and `foo` is a folder full of files, Git updates (i.e., replaces) each of the various `foo/*` *files* that appear in its index, and adds to its index any new `foo/*` *files* that are in the `foo` folder (provided they're not listed in an exclusion entry). A subsequent commit then stores, in the new commit, whatever files are in Git's index—including all the *old* files whose names are `dir/*`. What you see when you examine a commit is, usually, the result of *comparing* the files in that commit to the same files in an earlier commit.

Comment: Hence, as @dan1st noted, the comparison of previous commit <hash1> to subsequent commit <hash2> might show that files `abc/file1` and `def/file2` are both different in that particular pair of commits. Should the set of changed-between-the-pair-of-snapshots files list only *one* such directory, you can get close to the answer you want.

Comment: The main Git tool to use to approach this problem is `git diff`, which can compare any two commits, or one commit and what's in your working tree right now, or one commit and what's in Git's index right now, or what's in Git's index right now and what's in your working tree right now. Normally, `git diff` prints out all the file names *and* their differences, but with `--name-only` you can limit the output to file names alone. This still requires post-processing to drop all but the top level directory part of a file name.

Comment: Should you wish to get even more detailed, Git provides what it calls *plumbing* commands, meant for use in writing new user-oriented commands, and these plumbing commands include `git diff-tree`, which exclusively compares just two trees (including the trees in the top level of any two commits). Without the `-r` (recurse) flag, this gets you much closer to what you want. Using it is a bit tricky, though, because it *is* a plumbing command, meant for use by other programs, not by humans.